# What code should I use, instead of running a query that uses DATA_FORMAT()?

Tags: 8, database

I am converting Drupal 7 code to Drupal 8. In Drupal 7, I am using `db_query()`; in Drupal 8, I am using the following code.

```php
\Drupal::database()->select('node_field_data', 'spmw')
  ->fields('spmw', ['id', 'created' => 'DATE_FORMAT(created, "%H:%i")'])
  ->execute()
  ->fetchObject();
```

When I run it, it causes the following error.

> 1054 Unknown column 'spmw.DATE_FORMATcreatedHi' in 'field list': SELECT spmw.id AS id, spmw.DATE_FORMATcreatedHi

What code should I instead use to avoid that error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try `\Drupal::database()->select->addExpression()`.

For you, below code might be useful.

```
\Drupal::database()
  ->select('node_field_data', 'spmw')
  ->fields('spmw', ['id'])
  ->addExpression("DATE_FORMAT(created,'%H:%i')", "created")
  ->execute()
  ->fetchObject();
```

Comment: Technically correct answer, but do not query the node_field_data table by hand. Always use entity query, then load those entities and display them.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, I would like to point out an alternate method.  The problem is that Drupal chokes on the parameter of the MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` function specifying how the date should be formatted.  Suppose you have this code:

```
$SQL = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%e %b %Y")';

$query = $db->query($SQL);

$query->execute();
```

Executing this in Drupal (as of version 8.8.2) will result in the message "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later." and the following entry in the log:

```
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[42S22]: 
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '%e %b %Y' in 'field list':
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), "%e %b %Y"); Array ( )
```

To work around that, you can use a bound parameter for the date format.  This code will work:

```
$SQL = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), :dateFormat)';
$terms = [':dateFormat' => '%e %b %Y'];

$query = $db->query($SQL, $terms);

$query->execute($terms);

$result = $query->fetchAll();
```

I suspect the `%` symbols in the `DATE_FORMAT` are what's causing the problem. Moving those to a bound parameter solves the issue because Drupal always passes those directly to the database as a literal string.

Hoping this may help some future sufferer.